# dpkg error while processing linux-image

Tags: apt, dpkg

I got problem with installing any package using apt-get.

i'm just trying to run simple command like

`sudo apt-get install package-name`

And I get this problem

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to  `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install package-name`, but problem was the same.

Ubuntu 19.10

UPDATE :

`$ sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install -f
Hit:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97,5 kB]

Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97,5 kB]

Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:5 https://desktop.userapi.com/debian stable InRelease

Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease [88,8 kB]

Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/stable/ubuntu eoan InRelease

Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`?

Comment: @starkus Thank you for your answer. I found, that 5.3.0-45 is broken, so i deleted it. Now, i got this problem  `dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
`

Comment: How did you remove 5.3.0-45?

Comment: Can you post what the terminal tells after `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @starkus I removed 5.3.0-45 using `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.3.0-45-generic && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @starkus I put an update to topic, to answer your second question

Comment: Not more? I would disable the sources with errors first, before continuing.